# Bundling tidy-html5 with PHP?

Tags: php

I want to setup the W3C fork of HTMLTidy ([tidy-html5](https://github.com/w3c/tidy-html5)) as a PHP extension.

I had installed the normal php/tidy extension using the `php5-tidy` package.

I then downloaded the Git repository, and ran the following commands to compile the shared library:

```
sh build/gnuauto/setup.sh && ./configure && make
sudo make install
```

After restarting the php5-fpm service, I still see the same tidy information on `phpinfo()`:

```
libTidy Release    25 March 2009
Extension Version  2.0 ($Id$)
```

Shouldn't the PHP extension start using `tidy-html5` at this point? What can I do to make it work?

Answer (score 1):

As I understand tidy-html5 is not a php module, so you can't use it directly with php. It's just a command line tools and/or shared library. You could try to build php with the new shared library

```
# configure ...
--with-tidy=shared,/usr/local/tidy-html5
```

Comment: That's right, it's a shared library. Regarding the PHP `configure` command, how can I preserve existing configure options? I'm asking this because I installed PHP and all the other extensions using either `apt` or `pecl` and I'm not sure what kind of magic goes into play there.

Answer (score 1):

One example how I use Tidy from within PHP:

```
$command = "tidy -indent -utf8 -xml -wrap 1000 data/cache/tidy-in.xml > data/cache/tidy-out.xml";
exec($command, $return, $code);
if ($code != 0) {
    throw new Exception(printf("Something went wrong: %s (%s)", join('<br />', $return), $code));
}
// the fixed version is here:
$html5 = file_get_contents('data/cache/tidy-out.xml');
```

With:

```
$command = "tidy -version";
exec($command, $return, $code);
if (count($return) > 0) {
    // command line tidy available
}
```

you can test if you have a command line tidy available. Formerly the HTML5-compatible version from Github had HTML5 in the version text, now it just says 'HTML Tidy for Linux version 4.9.18' but I think that's enough to work with (for example if you want to differentiate between HTML5 compatible and basic tidy).

Another option:

```
if (extension_loaded("tidy")) {
    // the non-HTML5 php extension... maybe it serves you as fallback..
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately, I'm not ubuntu/debian expert (As I see you have used apt). On RHEL based system I just download and install http://dl.iuscommunity.org/pub/ius/stable/Redhat/6/SRPMS/php53u-5.3.26-2.ius.el6.src.rpm, edit /root/rpmbuidl/SPESC/php53u.spec and rebuild rpm package

```
# rpmbuild -ba --target=x86_64 php53u.spec
```

As far as I know, on debian you can rebuild package too. Something like

```
$ sudo apt-get install devscripts build-essential fakeroot
$ apt-get source libapache2-mod-php5 php5-tidy
$ sudo apt-get build-dep libapache2-mod-php5
$ debuild -us -uc
```